# Is there an easy way to speed up this double summation in Mathematica

Tags: summation

I would like to make an intensity plot of Bosons in a harmonic trapping potential. Hence, I would like to execute the following double summation (everything made dimensionless) for as many terms as possible

```
wavefunc[x_, n_] := 
1/(Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] Sqrt[π]]) Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]

Intensity[x_, y_, μ_, nxmax_, nymax_] := Sum[(1/(Exp[((nx + ny + 1)/25 - μ)] - 1))
           (wavefunc[x, nx]* wavefunc[y, ny])^2, {nx, 0, nxmax}, {ny, 0, nymax}]
```

Subsequently I would like to plot as follows

```
Plot[Intensity[x, 0, -1/5, 75, 75], {x, -15, 15}].
```

Note that the factor of 1/25 in the intensity expression above is related to a certain value of the temperature. A typical value for $\mu$ would be $-1/5$. However, if I take $n_{x_{max}} = n_{y_{max}} = 75$, this already takes a very long time. I am aware that the number of terms goes as $O(n^2)$. Still, I would be very happy if there would be some way to speed this up in Mathematica by some option of some sort, as I only expect full convergence for $n_{x_{max}}$ a multiple of 25.

Comment: Note: you have missed the closing round bracket in `wavefunc`

Comment: You can memoize wavefunc. That should make it way quicker.

Comment: The biggest problem probably is that `Intensity` is defined using `SetDelayed`, which forces `Plot` to evaluate the sum for every single choice of `x` value. Do instead `With[{plt = Intensity[x, 0, -1/5, 75, 75]}, Plot[plt, {x, -15, 15}]]`.

Comment: @march I did have something like that before, but somehow Mathematica cannot handle the number of terms in the sum, which one can see by comparing the plots for nmax=60 and 75. There seem to be some divergences which are definitely not in the mathematical expression.

Comment: Sure, I saw those, too, and I assumed that there was some sort of numerical error occurring, but they seem to appear in your version as well. If you look at the expression that `Intensity` spits out, there are some HUGE numbers appearing. It's not wonder that there are numerical issues. Anyway, your question was about speed-up, which the `With` solution (or one of @MarcoB's solutions below) fixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do two things: 1) use machine-precision evaluation, rather than arbitrary precision ones as you are currently doing; 2) memoize the `wavefun` function so values used more than once do not have to be recalculated.

```
intensity[x_, y_, μ_, nxmax_, nymax_] := Sum[(1/(Exp[((nx + ny + 1)/25 - μ)] - 1)) (wavefunc[x, nx]*wavefunc[y, ny])^2, {nx, 0, nxmax}, {ny, 0, nymax}]

(* original definition, for comparison *)
Clear[wavefunc]
wavefunc[x_, n_] := 1/(Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] Sqrt[π]]) Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]
intensity[x, 0, -1/5, 75, 75]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* machine precision: note the 1. instead of 1 *)
Clear[wavefunc]
wavefunc[x_, n_] := 1./(Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] Sqrt[π]]) Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]
intensity[x, 0, -1/5, 75, 75]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* memoized and machine-precision *)
Clear[wavefunc]
wavefunc[x_, n_] := wavefunc[x, n] = 1./(Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] Sqrt[π]]) Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]
intensity[x, 0, -1/5, 75, 75]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Timing results are as follows:

```
original:                       3.96246 s
machine-precision evaluation:   1.29093 s ( 3x faster)
machine precision and memoized: 0.11249 s (36x faster)
```

---

**UPDATE:** As you and @march mentioned, your expressions suffer from numerical precision issues probably due to the Hermite polynomials. Machine-precision evaluation is therefore inadvisable, but still, combining memoization of arbitrary-precision `wavefun` with calculating `intensity` only once before passing it to `Plot` should give an appreciable speedup.

```
Clear[wavefunc]
wavefunc[x_, n_] :=
  wavefunc[x, n] =
   1/(Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] Sqrt[\[Pi]]]) Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]

(plot = With[
     {expr = intensity[x, 0, -1/5, 75, 75]},
     Plot[expr, {x, -40, 40}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   ];) // AbsoluteTiming

plot

(* Out: {13.9598, Null} *)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Note the most recent comment by the OP in the OP. There are also some numerical stability issues it seems.

Comment: @march I noticed that as well, while playing with the machine-precision version. I amended my answer accordingly, also including your suggestion to prevent needless recalculation of the `intensity` expression.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your reply. Indeed, your code gives a good speed-up. However, to ensure convergence I need to take a lot more terms into account. Going to 100 terms, the results becomes 'weird', probably due to numerical errors as you mentioned. Is there any way this can be fixed?