# Follow up: how to evaluate this double sum quickly

Tags: export, list-manipulation, summation

This question is a follow-up to [my previous question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95144/is-there-an-easy-way-to-speed-up-this-double-summation-in-mathematica)

The code I use at the moment is the following:

```
Bose[k_, μ_, nx_, ny_] := 1/(Exp[( k (nx + ny + 1) - μ)] - 1)
wavefunc[x_, n_] := 1/Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] π] Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]
Intensity[k_, x_, y_, μ_, nmax_] := Sum[Bose[k, μ, nx, ny] (wavefunc[x, nx]*wavefunc[y, ny])^2, {nx, 0, nmax}, {ny, 0, nmax}]
```

Using this, I can now easily make plots with the following line (which was a suggestion in the answer to the previous question)

```
(pt1 = With[{expr = Intensity[Ω, x, 0, μ1, nmax]}, 
      Plot[expr, WorkingPrecision -> 50, {x, -40, 40}];)
Show[pt1]
```

This sums up $500^2$ terms in about 4 minutes if I take a large working precision. (Typical values are $\Omega = 1/150$ and $\mu = 1/2 * \Omega$).

However, I would like to export the graph as data points in a .dat file, such that I can use the data elsewhere. This again suffers from extremely long running times. The code I use is

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := Array[# &, n, {a, b}]
xarr = linearmesh[-40, 40, 160];
soly1 = Monitor[Table[Intensity[Ω, xarr[[i]], 0, μ, 150], {i, 1,Ngrid}], i];
Export["fit.dat", soly1]
```

but even for 150 terms this takes forever. Is there an easy way to speed this up significantly?

Comment: You'd better add the definitions of `μ` and `Ω` and `nmax` into the code rather than state in the text of your question. Also, you forgot to add the definition of `Ngrid` (though it's not hard to guess that it's `160`.) Finally, your code cotains typo, the `With` in `pt1` loses its right bracket, and the position of `WorkingPrecision` option is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already got `pt1` in 4 minutes (well, your computer really owns a huge memory, my 8G laptop exceeds the memory limitation while ploting `pt1`!), you can just dig out those data points in `pt1`:

```
data = Cases[pt1, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]];
Export["fit.dat", data]
SystemOpen@Directory[]
```

My memory exhausted, so I can't test the code, but it should work.

Then I'd like to say something about your new trial. I think its slowness is mainly because of the use of exact number rather than arbitrary precision number. Indeed, though still a little faster than symbolic calculation, arbitrary precision calculation is already slow:

```
Ω = 1/150; μ = Ω/2;
nmax = 150;
eg1 = Intensity[Ω, 1`50, 0, μ, nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming 
eg2 = Intensity[Ω, 1, 0, μ, nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {10.150728, Null} *)
(* {13.089546, Null} *)
```

But don't forget `eg2` is a symbolic expression! When exported as a `.dat`, it becomes something like:

```
Export["a.dat", eg2] // SystemOpen
```

[image] 
*Pictured by Simon Wood's [shadow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43187/1871).*

Such expression is undoubtedly slow in exporting, and most of all, undesired for your subsequent processing. You can add something like `N[…, 50]` to `soly1` to fix your new code.